# Multithreaing in java - drools and database

Tags: java, multithreading

I am pretty new to multi threading and tried something to apply it, but I am kinda stuck.

Here is the scenario:
using drools to apply rules on a set of objects read from the db, then write the updated values back to the db.

Now, I repeat the above process multiple times, so i want to run the reading+drool process in one thread(main thread) and the writing part in another.

So I write the below code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() 
{     public void run()
    { 
         try 
         {
    //writing the updated data in DB    
    aggregationDAO.updateCaseDetailsInOracle(queryList);
    } 
         catch (Exception e) {                              throw new RuntimeException();
    }
   }
});
    thread.start();
```

But, I am stuck here.

Firstly, it expects my `queryList` to be final.

I cannot make it final coz every time new updated data loads in the same variable.

Secondly,

even after making my program run multi threads, there is no improvement in my run time.

Can, someone tell me where I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use your custom thread instead of 'main', so there is no improvment. There is no 'multi' threading in your example.

If you want to see speed improvment, you should run several thread simultaniously.
Use some sort of thread pool for concurrent task processing, and then you will get improvment.

Also, variable must be final, because you are creating anonymous class - Runnable. You should create new class wich will implements Runnable and pass into constructor your variable.

```
class QueryTask implements Runnable {
    private final List queryList;
    public QueryTask(List queryList) {
        this.queryList = queryList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try { //writing the updated data in DB
            aggregationDAO.updateCaseDetailsInOracle(queryList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
threadPool.submit(new QueryTask(queryList.subList(0, 5)));
threadPool.submit(new QueryTask(queryList.subList(6, 10)));
```

This will process your queryList by portions concurrently.

**UPDATE:**

When you already submit all your tasks, you can shutdown threadPool and wait while all tasks will be done.
You can not add any new task after that.

```
    threadPool.shutdown();
    try {
        threadPool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {               
        // Current thread was interrupted.
        final List<Runnable> runnables = threadPool.shutdownNow();
        System.out.println("Can't stop tasks: " + runnables.size());

        // Restore interrupted status.
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

Comment: So if i make queryList as final then how do i populate it with new data that comes in next cycle ??

Comment: thanks for the quick reply !!

but lemme explain my scenario a bit more..

I have a list which is send to the db and a list of map of data is read, now because this data is very large i have to divide this reading process into parts(to avoid overflow), on each part i apply rules and some data is updated and a this data is to be updated into the db.

Now, my applying rules and updating db takes the maximum time, so i was thinking of running these two steps parallely !!

Comment: @abhinay You should think how to separate your data on some parts, then make runnable tasks, pass your data portions in that tasks and run them in threadPool. You can make fixed thread pool, submit all your tasks into it at once, and there will be no overflow because there are will be only fixed amount of running tasks at the same time. You can create fixed thread pool size using this: Executors.newFixedThreadPool(i)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now i have got hold of my mistake. Thank you so much!!

Just one more help, what should i do if i wish my main thread to wait for the completion of these new threads?

Comment: It's my pleasure. Read more about threadPools, they have many features. The simplest way to wait for all tasks is in my update for the answer.